# NoReverseMatch error - simple calendar app

Tags: python, django, url, view

I cannot figure out how to solve this problem.

I have tried to make a simple calendar using lightbird tutorial. What I got is the following error:

```
Reverse for 'cal.views.main' with arguments '(2011,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$']
```

And this is the reason why this error occurs:

```
<a href="{% url "cal.views.main" year|add:'-3' %}">&lt;&lt; Prev</a>
```

My cal/views.py file contains:

```
def main(request, year=None):
    ...
    return render_to_response("cal/main.html", dict(years=lst, user=request.user, year=year,))
```

My main.html file contains:

```
{% extends "cal/base.html" %}
{% load url from future %}
<!-- ... -->
{% block title %} Cal {% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<a href="{% url "cal.views.main" year|add:'-3' %}">&lt;&lt; Prev</a>
{% endblock %}
```

My ulrs.py file contains:

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^$', 'cal.views.main', name="main"),
```

Lastly, the whole tree consisting of my project files looks like this (I have listed the most important files):

```
website
 - cal
 - - models.py
 - - views.py
 - website
 - - static
 - - templates
 - - - cal
 - - - - base.html
 - - - - main.html
 - - urls.py
```

Comment: Your url pattern is not capturing anything that it will send to the view, which is why you are getting the error.

Comment: Could you, please, tell me how to fix it? I see it, I have an error probably in url pattern, but I do not have the faintest idea what to change in this case.

Comment: Your pattern for the main view is `^$` which is just a blank URL; in other words, the default URL. You need to add a regular expression to capture the year that you are passing in, and then send it to your view method as the `year` keyword argument. Have a read through [part 3 of the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/#url-argument-regex) which explains this in detail.

Comment: url(r"^(\d+)/$", 'cal.views.year', name="year"), that is what I tried to do, but I still get an error (in this care my error is: 'str object is not callable)

Comment: Your view is called `main` not `year`, the error is `cal.view.year` doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok, changing "year" with the existing view partially solved my problem. Thank you! Could you please also tell me how to refer to cal.views.month to display the month? Should "month" be rendered to response in views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `url(r"^(\d+)/$", 'cal.views.year', name="year"),` that is what I tried
>   to do, but I still get an error (in this care my error is: 'str object
>   is not callable)
>
> ...
>
> Ok, changing "year" with the existing view partially solved my
>   problem. Thank you! Could you please also tell me how to refer to
>   cal.views.month to display the month? Should "month" be rendered to
>   response in views?

URL patterns in django have two required arguments:

1. The pattern to match.
2. The function to call when the pattern in matched.

The second argument must be an *existing* function (or class) in your views. The function can take multiple arguments, and appear in multiple patterns.

For example, suppose you have a method like this:

```
def display_events(request, year=None, month=None, day=None):
    # do something to filter events
    events = Event.objects.all()
    if year:
       events.filter(event_date__year=year)
    if month:
       events.filter(event_date__month=month)
    if day:
       events.filter(event_date__day=day)

    return render(request, 'events_list.html', {'events': events})
```

You want to map it to the following URLs:

- /events/2014
- /events/2014/06
- /events/2014/06/05

Here is how you would set it up:

```
url(r'^events/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})$',
   'cal.vews.display_events', name='daily'),

url(r'^events/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})$',
   'cal.views.display_events', name='monthly'),

url(r'^events/(?P<year>\d{4})$',
   'cal.views.display_events', name='yearly'),

url(r'^events/$', 'cal.views.display_events', name='all-events'),
```

The complicated part is the regular expression, a [short intro is provided in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/#url-argument-regex):

- `r'` (this is a Python raw string, which means everything is taken literally and special characters are not interpreted).
- `^` - start of string
- `events/` - the literal string *events/*
- `(` - start of a capturing group. This means, everything that matches the expression until the closing `)` will be captured (returned) by the engine.
- `?P<year>` - this means *"whatever is captured in the group, return it the name 'year'"*.
                 These are called *named capture groups*.
                 See the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for more.
- `\d` - A number
- `{4}` - exactly four of the previous pattern
- `)` - close of the capture group
- `$` - end of string
- `'` - end the raw string

The long verbose version of the above is:

*Search the url. If you see `events/` followed by exactly four numbers, capture these four numbers and send them as the name `year` as an argument to the view method with the name `display_events` which will be in the `views` module of the `cal` module.*

Applications in django are just Python modules.

Since patterns are applied in the first order they are matched, you should place the most "liberal" pattern *last*, so that if nothing else matches, it will match.

All these patterns point to the *same* view method. Just that depending on what is matched in the URL, the different arguments will be passed.

Finally, keep in mind that URL patterns cannot match query strings (the part after the `?` in a URL). This information is always passed to the view in the dict-like object `request.GET`.

Comment: I have added the following pattern for months:  `url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})$',views.main, name='month'),`
According to your tutorial, it should work properly, but it does not. In html file I have the following line of code: `<a href="{% url "cal.views.main" year month.n %}">{{ month.name }}</a>`